# at or in the middle of the picture

Tags: grammar, prepositions, prepositional-phrases

Suppose I have a picture of something. Suppose further that there is a cut in the middle of the picture.

So, is it correct to say:

*There is a cut in the middle of the picture*

or

*There is a cut at the middle of the picture*

and Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's correct to say **in the middle** as this is idiomatic and comes naturally to native English speakers. Google Books Ngram Viewer indicates a strong return for **in the middle** and virtually none for **at the middle**. If you ask why, it's because that's the way the language has developed.

In the examples you give, the word **middle** is a noun. However, you can also use it as an adjective, as in **the middle point** or **the middle line**. Then the preposition you would use is likely to change.

Most people would say **at the middle point** (because we talk about **at a point**) and **on the middle line** (because we say things are **on a line** or sometimes **in a line**, which means something different.)

These are conventions rather than rules and are not absolute. Depending on the context, other prepositions may be suitable, e.g.: **in the line of fire** and **on the point of political correctness**.

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=at+the+middle%2Cin+the+middle&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cat%20the%20middle%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20middle%3B%2Cc0